# why hyperlink with www does not visible

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I was trying to make an hyperlink, I found something I don't understand.

The hyper link below doesn't show up on my html view with `www` in it.

```
href='http://www.ringtonematcher.com/co/ringtonematcher/02/noc.php?sid=EULDros&artist=$ringtone_artist&song=$ringtone_title
```

but when I remove `www` it start showing up

```
href='http://ringtonematcher.com/co/ringtonematcher/02/noc.php?sid=EULDros&artist=$ringtone_artist&song=$ringtone_title
```

Is there any explanation?

Thankyou

EDIT 1
Here is my view source

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<title>Music Engine</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainbody" class="wrapper">
    <script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
    <script>
          SC.initialize({
            client_id: "6a43a20c7a9e04da8d722bb01f16ce49",
          });      
          SC.get('/tracks/106285389',function(track){SC.oEmbed(track.permalink_url, document.getElementById("player"));})
        $(document).ready(function() {
        });
    </script>
        <div id="player"></div>
        <a class="download" href="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/106285389/download?client_id=6a43a20c7a9e04da8d722bb01f16ce49">Download</a>

        <div class="ringtone_matcher"><a class='download' href='http://www.ringtonematcher.com/co/ringtonematcher/02/noc.php?sid=EULDros&artist=Carly Rae Jepsen&song=Call Me Maybe'>Send Ringtone to your cell</a></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

what i mean not visible is i can't see it in the browser but i can see it inside the source

Comment: Can you show the code you are using with the <a> tag, etc. That'd be a tremendous help.

Comment: Yes please post more of the surrounding code.

Comment: I can't find any php in the above code?

Comment: yeah sorry, just updated my code

Comment: Do you use some kind of CMS?

Comment: The browser doesn't see your PHP code, it merely sees the generated HTML. We can't really say how it looks like since you are using some undisclosed variables. You can use your browser's "View source" feature to find out.

Comment: veelen no sir i just use php

Comment: What do you mean with "the hyperlink is not visible"; is it not showing on your page, or doesn't it direct to the targeted page?

Comment: I can see here www in my local sysym

Comment: I was able to replicate is action in JSFIDDLE - http://jsfiddle.net/Ay7nE/1/. It works in static HTML page though. Ar you including any jqeury or external libraries?

Comment: @ConradLotz hai do see it inside jsfiddle? because i can't seem to see it, tried with chrome still the same

Comment: Maybe you've some process behind rewriting something ?

How does the code source appear in your browser once displayed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`www.ringtonematcher.com` is on a list of unwelcome advertising sites in AdBlock, which applies a stylesheet which applies `display: none` to links to it. The site without the `www.` is not on that list.

Disable your AdBlock extension to see it.

Comment: omg this is the problem, ringtone matcher url is blocked with my adblockplus add on. thank you so much

Comment: hmm is there any trick to make it visible even without disabling adblock?

Comment: Go to the adblock preferences and uncheck "Hide placeholders of blocked elements".

Answer (score 0):

The problem would seem to be from the fact that you aren't effectively "showing" the language of PHP that you have variables in your code.

```
<div class="ringtone_matcher">
<?php echo "<a class='download' href='http://ringtonematcher.com/co/ringtonematcher/02/noc.php?sid=EULDros&artist=".$ringtone_artist."&song=".$ringtone_title."'>";
        echo "Send Ringtone to your cell</a>";
?>
</div>
```

This would, at least, be a more correct way of doing it.

Comment: thankyou but i don't think this is the problem, i have tried your code but when i add `http://www.ringtonematcher.com` the hyperlink is not visible

Comment: I suppose it isn't less correct, however I have experienced troubles with it.